# How do I the sum of all prime numbers those are less than 2144 and print the result..?

Tags: c#-4.0

Here is my code but the sum is not accumulating correctly that is a big number.

Do I need to use BigInteger ?

If so how because I have no clue how to use BigInteger to do the total.

```
namespace ConsolePrimeNumbers
{

    public static class PrimeTool
    {
        public static bool IsPrime(int candidate)
        {
            // Test whether the parameter is a prime number.
            if ((candidate & 1) == 0)
            {
                if (candidate == 2)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            // Note:
            // ... This version was changed to test the square.
            // ... Original version tested against the square root.
            // ... Also we exclude 1 at the very end.
            for (int i = 3; (i * i) <= candidate; i += 2)
            {
                if ((candidate % i) == 0)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return candidate != 1;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--- Primes between 0 and 214.......");  
            long total = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 2144; i++)
            {
                bool prime = PrimeTool.IsPrime(i);
                if (prime)
                {
                    Console.Write("Prime: ");
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                    total = total + i;
                }

            }
            Console.Write("Total of All Prime: ");
            Console.WriteLine(total);

        }

     }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not accumulating correctly"?

Comment: Your sum does fit in a long, a BigInteger is not needed. Why do you think this does not work? What does it print?

Answer (score 1):

Your IsPrime function is wrong. The loop condition is (i * i) <= candidate. What about IsPrime(14)? The loop stops at i=3 (because at i=4, i*i = 16). You actually want it to get up to i=7 before you can terminate the loop. It's likely that you want (i*2) <= candidate. Otherwise it's returning true for a lot of numbers that aren't actually prime.

Comment: I did made changes in the code ... for (int i = 3; (i * 2) <= candidate; i += 2) but its still not displaying the correct total. I think total is a big number and any idea how I can solve this please ...thanks

Comment: I need help to add all the prime numbers and then print the total ...please

Comment: Hi Peter, Could you kindly assist me to solve this problem please.